# Take difference in time stamps to initiate logout in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

In my `jmeter` script, I want to apply a logic where I take the `time stamp` of the first request and the second last request with the last request being `logout`. The difference in the `time stamps` when exceeds `3600 sec` should trigger the `logout` transaction. I can take the `time stamps` using the `jmeter _time function` but not able to subtract it successfully. If I can get this done then I can put `logout` in an if controller and give the condition. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [__longSum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__longSum) which you can use to subtract 2 [Unix timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

1. Define start as: `${__time(,start)}` where required
2. Define end as: `${__time(,end)}` where required
3. You can get the difference between `end` and `start` as `${__longSum(${start},-${end},)}`

   Demo:

   [image: JMeter delta between timestamps]

More information: [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii)